# CTRL+SPACE binding in 17.10

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 17.10

Something in 17.10 is preventing me from binding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to be the launcher key for albert.

When I'm in certain windows it will work (e.g. firefox), but in any "os" windows, e.g. terminal, file browser, settings window, etc., <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> does not bring up albert.

When I'm in the file browser, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> seems to do something with the currently selected file (can't figure out what).

I've been looking around in `gnome-tweak-tool` for a way to disable these existing hotkeys, but I can't seem to find where they are defined.

This was working fine in 16.04. Please advise